# Running jar with -Dloader.path= works, but not application.properties loader.path

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jar

I have an external properties file under /config/application.properties which I retrieve properties from. When I run my jar, it is able to pick up certain properties from it, (e.g. server.port=8083)

This is the structure of my files/folders:

```
ProjectFolder
 |
 +-- mytool.jar
 |    
 +-- config
 |  |  
 |  +-- application.properties
 |    
 +-- lib
 |  |  
 |  +-- externalJar.jar
```

Now, the problem is that I need the property "loader.path" from the external properties file, all other properties are being loaded correctly except for loader.path when I run the jar with:

```
java -jar mytool.jar
```

Inside the external application.properties contains:

```
spring.servlet.multipart.enabled=false
server.port = 8083
logging.file = /someplace/
loader.path=lib
```

Since it is not loading the externalJar.jar, I encounter classNotFoundExceptions.

However, what's strange is that when I start the app with:

```
java -Dloader.path=lib -jar mytool.jar
```

Everything works as expected.

Am I missing something with the application.properties file?
I have tried using the full path:

```
loader.path=/home/me/ProjectFolder/lib
```

but that didn't work either. 
I am confident that the application.properties is being read because the server.port number showing up on boot is the one I specifically specified.

I've changed the project to use the PropertiesLauncher in Maven.
MANIFEST.MF

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Implementation-Title: mytool
Implementation-Version: 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
Built-By: giraffepoo
Implementation-Vendor-Id: com.sap
Spring-Boot-Version: 2.1.3.RELEASE
Main-Class: org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher
Start-Class: com.sap.mytool
Spring-Boot-Classes: BOOT-INF/classes/
Spring-Boot-Lib: BOOT-INF/lib/
Created-By: Apache Maven 3.3.9
Build-Jdk: 1.8.0_201
Implementation-URL: https://projects.spring.io/spring-boot/#/spring-bo
 ot-starter-parent/mytool
```

If someone could point me in the right direction, your help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Note:
Not sure if related, but the externalJar.jar is utilized immediately when the application starts up in the overridden method: contextInitialized

Comment: Do you have the solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

I know that there is a kindda old question, but still without answear. I think the problem lays that the `loader.path` property should be provided in the standalone `loader.properties` file. [As it is described in documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#executable-jar.launching).

Also keep in mind that it works only for `PropertiesLauncher`, not for `JarLauncher` or `WarLauncher`.